# react-native-calendar : How to select limited number of days

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-calendars

I am using [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) for my project. I am able to select days `ON/OFF`.

However, I want user to have limitation when selecting days. So I want to let users to pick up to `3 days`.

If more than `3days are selected`, disable the `selected method`.

Any idea how I can do this? Any comments or advice would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
 onDaySelect = (day) => {

    const _selectedDay = moment(day.dateString).format(_format);
    let selected = true;
    let markedDates = {}
    if (this.state._markedDates[_selectedDay]) {
      selected = !this.state._markedDates[_selectedDay].selected;
      markedDates = this.state._markedDates[_selectedDay];
    }

    markedDates = {...markedDates, ...{ selected }};
    const updatedMarkedDates = {...this.state._markedDates, ...{ [_selectedDay]: markedDates } }
    this.setState({ _markedDates: updatedMarkedDates },
    ()=> {console.log(this.state._markedDates, 'this.state._markedDates')});
    this.setState({bday:day.dateString}
    , ()=> {
    store.requestObject.date = this.state.bday
    })
  }


 <Calendar
                   onDayPress={this.onDaySelect}
                   markedDates={this.state._markedDates}
                   markingType={'multi-dot'}
                   monthFormat={'yyyy MMMM'}/>
```

State:

```
const _format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
const _today = moment().format(_format)
  initialState = {
       [_today]: {disabled: true}
   }

this.state = {_markedDates: this.initialState}
```

Comment: Can you add your `markedDates` state as well?

Comment: @iRohitBhatia sure I will edit my code.